# grep between timestamps from logs in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have the following logs

```
2022-07-23T09:00:00,987 hi
2022-07-23T10:00:00,987 hi
2022-07-23T11:10:00,987 hi
2022-07-23T12:52:00,987 hi
2022-07-23T13:29:00,987 hi
2022-07-23T13:59:00,987 hi
```

I want to grep only the lines between 10 AM to 13:30 PM. Here is my command, but it doesn't retrieve the result as expected. Any ideas where it has to fix

```
sudo cat <path to my log file> | grep 'hi' | grep -E '2022-07-23T(10:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|13:30:00)'
```

Comment: Very strange closing. Is `grep` not one of the `software tools primarily used by programmers.`?

Comment: @anubhava can you please vote for reopen, not sure why this is closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is better tool for this than `grep`:

```bash
awk -F '[T,]' '$2 >= "10:00" && $2 <= "13:30" && /hi/' file

2022-07-23T10:00:00,987 hi
2022-07-23T11:10:00,987 hi
2022-07-23T12:52:00,987 hi
2022-07-23T13:29:00,987 hi
```

Here:

- Using `-F '[T,]'` we delimit fields on `T` or `,` chars
- `awk -F '[T,]' '$2 >= "10:00" && $2 <= "13:30"` does lexicological comparison of 2nd field with our data range
- `/hi/` search for `hi` in a line

---

Here is a `grep` solution using regex magic:

```bash
grep -E '^[^T]+T1([0-2]|3:([0-2][0-9]|30)):.* hi' file

2022-07-23T10:00:00,987 hi
2022-07-23T11:10:00,987 hi
2022-07-23T12:52:00,987 hi
2022-07-23T13:29:00,987 hi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZJVLSl/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^T]+`:
- `T1`: Match `T` followed by digit `1`
- `([0-2]|3:([0-2][0-9]|30))`: Match digits `0 to 2` to match time starting with `10` or `11` or `12`. After alternation we match hour `13` followed by minutes `00` to `29` or `30`
- `:.* hi`: Match `:` followed by any string followed by a space and `hi`

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, I'm looking for grep, would you mind for grep?

Comment: `grep` cannot *easily* do range checks but I will provide a `grep` just for you

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, as I don't have access for awk, hence requesting for grep

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, I'm looking to tweak it for the following timestamp 9 AM - 5:30 PM

Comment: That would be `grep '^[^T]+T(09|1[0-6]|17:([0-2][0-9]|30)):.* hi' file`

Comment: Accepted, I have one more question regarding extracting specific logs between two separate log files in a single command. Is that possible

Comment: Regarding additional question it may be better to post a new question with some sample data so that I can look into that and answer there.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, will do, a small request, I'm struggling with the same regex to update it to 17:30 to 9:00 - https://regex101.com/r/Jx4BrU/1
Would you be able to help me

Comment: I looked at it, it is from 9:00 to 17:30, and  now I'm looking for the other side, I mean from 17:30 to 09:00 - I hope you got my point

Comment: ok [see this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jx4BrU/3)

Comment: You are a truly master. Would you mind explaining the pattern, so that I can do it on my own from next time? 
^[^T]+T(0[0-8]|1[89]|2[0-3]|17:[3-5][0-9]):.* hi

Comment: I have already explained `10:00` to `13:30` pattern in answer. This is on similar lines. You can also see this website: https://3widgets.com/ for numeric regex generation

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, Most the pattern I understood it. But, got confused on this one 1[89]|2[0-3], like what does 89 stands for

Comment: That is for matching hours of time `18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23`